# Peering in Local Network

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I have a Network which has a Few Internet users. In my analysis, i found the most of Network (Bandwidth) is used on Torrents and that too downloading the same torrent by multiple users at different time. So what i am planning is, to install a cache server in between for Torrent downloads and serve the torrent data from there. For this i need one important thing. Want to Know which torrent they are downloading on my network. is there a way to find the hash of the Torrent, so i can have them downloaded in my Network and peer them. this is has to happen with out The end user intervention. Don't say have server like ZBIGZ or online torrenting sites.

Comment: Interesting question - it creates a minefield of legal questions if doing this is possible, but it would be interesting to see none-theless.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible. This is not how torrents work.

Caching torrents will not improve downloads or the network - if the caching server was even possible. The torrent protocol has many layers to prevent what your are asking. End to end encryption for example.

If the same torrent was being download by multiple people in the network the protocol will optimize accordingly by finding and prioritizing LAN connections. A caching server will only slow down the downloads.

This is also against the philosophy of torrents. Will your caching server also Seed and give back to the community? Will the clients behind the caching server also give back? If so, a caching server is again useless.